# Datepicker is Jumbled

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

This one has me pulling my hair out.

I'm trying to implement a very simple jQuery datepicker. I'm using code straight out of the example online.

I've finally started over with a blank page with no CSS (aside from the Redmond jquery UI theme. When I view the page, I get a blue bar below my text box:

http://gameguidesonline.com/brian/1.png

...Mousing over this bar causes a javascript error.

If I click on the date box, I get this jumbled version of the datepicker:

http://gameguidesonline.com/brian/2.png

**html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
        <link type="text/css" href="/JavaScript/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
        <script src="/JavaScript/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/JavaScript/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="bench.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div class="demo">
                <p>Date: <input id="datepicker" type="text" /></p>
            </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**bench.js:**

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

**Versions**

jQuery v1.7.1 (also tried 1.7)
jQuery UI 1.8.16
IE 9, Firefox (latest)

I even tried a script I found that waits until onclick to bind the calendar. This gets rid of the blue bar, but still shows me a jumbled calendar.

Comment: It looks like your css is making the fonts too big to scale well.

Comment: Can you post a link to live example, JSFiddle maybe?

Comment: @scott.korin: I don't have any CSS here. The only CSS is from the redmond theme.

Comment: @JaspreetChahal This is .net and it wouldn't be blue if the path was wrong. :/

Comment: Can you post the JS Error from the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the following code directly. The difference is I used google CDN paths to javascript. It works prefectly. I used the versions you have mentioned.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
<!--        <link type="text/css" href="/JavaScript/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
-->         <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.16/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div class="demo">
                <p>Date: <input id="datepicker" type="text" /></p>
            </div>

    </form>
    <script src="bench.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ...That... Does work perfectly. Good God. So what does that mean, I've got a corrupt version of Redmond somehow?!

Comment: Not sure. Try downloading the files once again, and also try moving your bench.js to end of the document since you are using self invoking function. Probably somebody can back me up here, that a self invoking function is run though the page flow, and if you want to place your script in head tag, replace your self invoking function with document.ready function to make sure it is run after dom is loaded.

Comment: Just wanted to follow up again and say thanks for your help, you probably saved me from wasting even more time. And I had a custom version of the CSS file, so I'm betting something was just missing. Simply switching to pull the CSS from google CDN fixed everything.